# Kubernetes internet access with two network interfaces

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I'm new in kubernetes and I have a question about kubernetes network.
In my setup each node has two interfaces. the first interface (eth0) is in private range (for example 172.20.12.10) and the second has a public address.

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.20.12.10
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 172.20.0.0
    broadcast 172.16.255.255
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address x.x.x.x
gateway y.y.y.y
```

apparently kubernetes network configurations depends on node default gateway so above node network configuration doesn't work correctly.

my question is : how can I access internet in my containers?

Answer (score 3):

The `--apiserver-advertise-address` argument for `kubeadm init` can be used to make k8s use an interface different than the default network interface of the nodes:

```
--apiserver-advertise-address string
    The IP address the API Server will advertise it's listening on.
    Specify '0.0.0.0' to use the address of the default network interface.
```

Also, add a flag to `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` that specifies the private IP of the worker node:

```
--node-ip=<private-node-ip>
```

Finally, when you run `kubeadm join` on the worker nodes, make sure you provide the private IP of the API server.

More info is in:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#using-internal-ips-in-your-cluster
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33618#issuecomment-250082421

Comment: now in containers I have internet access and also private network but cannot access other containers (for example it can not access kubernetes dns service)